# Get max for all columns between row index 0 and row index X

Tags: pandas, dataframe

If I have dataframe with 4 columns and N rows:

```
data = {'col0' : [85, 75, 85, 87, 91, 83],
        'col1' : [85, 75, 85, 87, 75, 81],
        'col2' : [35, 45, 83, 35, 45, 83],
        'col3' : [51, 61, 45, 51, 91, 45]}
frame = pd.DataFrame(data)
print(frame)
```

so here's frame:

```
   col0  col1  col2  col3
0    85    85    35    51
1    75    75    45    61
2    85    85    83    45
3    87    87    35    51
4    91    75    45    91
5    83    81    83    45
```

what's an elegant way to get maximum for each column between row index 0 and row index X, where X (the row index) is different for each column, and available in an array. So len(arrX) == len(df.columns).

Comment: Could you share what you tried? So we know how elegant we need to be.

Comment: `df.iloc[:x,:].max(axis=1)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is something you could try:

```
arrX= [2,3,4,5]
max_cols = {'max_'+col_name: max(frame[col_name][0:arrX[i]]) for i,col_name in enumerate(frame.columns)}
```

Answer:

```
print(max_cols)
>>> {'max_col0': 85, 'max_col1': 85, 'max_col2': 83, 'max_col3': 91}
```

Comment: I'm iterating over all columns, one at a time, in a simple for loop and appending the max value to a list. Your approach with a single line syntax does make it all compact and elegant! I however modified your approach to output a list rather than a set, so its ordered rather than unordered. *** max_cols = [frame.iloc[:arrX[i],i].max() for i in range(len(frame.columns))]